# Kendo: DropDownList fill container

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Using Kendo UI in MVC 4
.

I have a dropdown defined as this in a table.td:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.AppUserStatus)
                                      .DataTextField("Text")
                                      .DataValueField("Value")
                                      .BindTo(@ViewBag.StatusList)

                                      )
```

How do I get it to fill the width of the table.td that it is contained in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add attributes directly with the wrapper via the **HtmlAttributes** method. In your case the following should do the work:

```
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" })
```